# How to properly use Model Collection in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, model, resource-model

I'm using Magento 2.3.4 , and i kinda confuse with how to use Magento 2 model correctly or follow the code standard. I have a model collection with database structure like this:

```
brand_id | name | type | manufacturer | priority | created_at | updated_at
```

I'm using Mage2gen.com to generate model, and got the following files:
https://mage2gen.com/load/33e2b596-8220-4434-b852-b55c2c95293a?main_version=3

[image]

when i want to add new or get record i do it like this:

```
public function __construct(
  \Vendor\Module\Model\BrandFactory $brandFactory,
){
  $brandFactory = $this->brandFactory;
}

//add new record to the table
function addNewBrand($data){
  $this->brandFactory->create()->setData($data)->save();
}

//update new record to the table
function updateBrand($data){
  $this->brandFactory->create()->load($data['id'])->setData($data)->save();
}

//get data by name
function getBrandByName($name){
  return $this->brandFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('name',$name)->getFirstItem();
}

//update data by name
function updateBrandByName($data){
  $model = $this->getBrandByName($data['name']);
  if(!$model->getId()) $model = $this->brandFactory->create();
  $model->setData($data)->save();
}

function getBrands(){
  return $this->brandFactory->create()->getCollection();
}
```

i always use the model factory to crud the data , but i just read in the documentation that this model is depecrated , what is the Correct way for me to do above functionality ?

Comment: you have the brand repository. Check if it has get/save/delete/getList methods

Answer (score 1):

You should use repositories instead of factory
https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories/